# Shopify Stores - View Creation Date of Store

Tags: shopify

I want to view a Shopify Store creation date, even without necessarily being an admin of the store

For example, the format should look something like
"2020-07-19T00:06:15.115Z"

However, I am currently unaware of which API endpoint to hit, or where on the site this information can be found.

I know it is possible to check the earliest uploaded product, but that doesn't neccesarily give you the date of site creation. and I'm not talking about date of domain creation, I'm talking about the actual shopify created_at date

Comment: What leads you to believe that's something Shopify make public?

Answer (score 1):

you can check the same using the REST API endpoint [shop](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/store-properties/shop)
you need to make a `GET` request using API to get the data about the shop.

This is the sample request code `GET /admin/api/2021-01/shop.json`
[image]

and here is the same request the contains the data about shop creation along with other data.
[image]